# Why can I assign two variables corresponding to an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

After about a year of Ruby, I just saw this somewhere and my mind is blown. Why in the world does this work?

```
>> words = ['uno', 'dos']
=> ["uno", "dos"]
>> first, second = words
=> ["uno", "dos"]
>> first
=> "uno"
>> second
=> "dos"
```

Specifically, how does this work:

```
>> first, second = ['uno', 'dos']
```

Why can I do this? It makes no syntactical sense!

Comment: It's surprising that you have never seen this in a year of Ruby. It's exactly what happens when for example iterating over a hash and using two block variables to separate the key and value instead of one two element array (`hash.each { |k, v| ... }` instead of `hash.each { |arr| ... }`

Comment: You can take this a lot further btw: `one, two, three, _, *rest = [*1..10]`.

Comment: @MichaelKohl I had actually been under the impression it was obtained with args[0], and args[1], but this makes much more sense! Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelKohl: Is _ a placeholder? I've never seen it in this context. I only know it from irb, as equal to the last result.

Comment: It basically means "I don't care about this". You know how you prefix variable names with `_` to denote that you are not intending to use the result without triggering a warning (e.g. `_foo`)? This is the same, just without even a name.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> It makes no syntactical sense

But this is *part* of Ruby's syntax! In the Ruby docs it is known as [array decomposition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition):

> Like Array decomposition in method arguments you can decompose an
> Array during assignment using parenthesis:
>
> ```
> (a, b) = [1, 2]
>
> p a: a, b: b # prints {:a=>1, :b=>2}
> ```
>
> You can decompose an Array as part of a larger multiple assignment:
>
> ```
> a, (b, c) = 1, [2, 3]
>
> p a: a, b: b, c: c # prints {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
> ```
>
> Since each decomposition is considered its own multiple assignment you
> can use * to gather arguments in the decomposition:
>
> ```
> a, (b, *c), *d = 1, [2, 3, 4], 5, 6
>
> p a: a, b: b, c: c, d: d
> # prints {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>[3, 4], :d=>[5, 6]}
> ```

#### Edit

as Stefan points out in the comments, the docs don't mention that array decomposition also occurs implicitly (i.e. without parenthesis) if there is only one value on the right-hand side:

`a, b = [1, 2]` works like `(a, b) = [1, 2]`

Comment: Also, it allows you to swap variables without needing a third one :
`a,b = b,a`

Comment: The docs don't mention that array decomposition also occurs implicitly (i.e. _without_ parenthesis) if there is only one value on the right-hand side: `a, b = [1, 2]` works like `(a, b) = [1, 2]`.

Comment: Thanks for the mention! I've [updated my example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/105716) to make use of the term "decomposition" instead and added an example of nested decomposition (been exposed to Clojure at the time of writing that). Also, feel free to amend it if you think something is missing there.

Answer (score 6):

> Why can I do this? It makes no syntactical sense!

It makes a perfect sense. It is an example of parallel assignment.

When you use `=` what is happening is each of the list of variables on the left of `=` are assigned to each of the list of expressions on the right of `=`.

```
first, second = ['uno', 'dos']
# is equivalent to
first, second = 'uno', 'dos'
```

If there are more variables on the left, than expressions on the right, those left variables are assigned with `nil`:

```
first, second = 'uno'
first  #=> 'uno'
second #=> nil
```

As to

```
words = ['uno', 'dos']
first, second = words
first  #=> 'uno'
second #=> 'dos'
```

It is not assigning the whole `words` array to `first` leaving `second` with `nil`, because while parallel assignment Ruby tries to decompose the right side expression, and does so if it is an instance of Array.

**[TIL]** Moreover, it attempts to call `to_ary` on the right side expression, and if it responds to the method, decomposes accordingly to that object's `to_ary` implementation (credits to [@Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477037/stefan)):

```
string = 'hello world'
def string.to_ary; split end
first, second = string
first  #=> 'hello'
second #=> 'world'
```

Comment: could you elaborate?

Comment: What about `first, second = words`? According to your explanation (more variables on the left, than expressions on the right), this should assign `words` to `first` and `nil` to `second`.

Comment: @Stefan yes, with this regard my answer is misleading and wrong.. I will consider either rephrasing it or deleting, thanks for noticing!

Comment: It raises the question why some objects are decomposed during (or before) parallel assignment and other's aren't.

Comment: @Stefan is it not simply because `words` is an array and thus being decomposed?

Comment: Additionally, it attempts to calls `to_ary`.  For example, `s = 'hello world'; def s.to_ary; split; end` would allow to assign words via `a, b = s`

Comment: @Stefan thank you very much for all the comments/advices you give - really appreciated! Also, I learn from them, which makes me feel really happy :)

Answer (score 0):

This is called multiple assignment, handy to assign multiple variables at once.
example

```
one, two = 1,2
puts one #=>1
puts two #=>2
one, two = [1,2] # this makes sense
one, two = 1  # obviously this doesn't it will assign nil to two
```

Hope its bit clear now